# Loop in different ranges VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Code below works good, but it needs modernization.
This code for one table, it works until the end of table. But I added addition table at the same page below actual (exist) table. I need jumping i (loop) through 3 empty cells and start code for next table below. In another words, to find next table below and implement code there too.
How to implement (realize) that?

```
Sub Test()
Dim score1 As Double, score2 As Double, score3 As Double, result As String, text As String

Dim ifrom As Long, ito As Long
Dim i As Long

ifrom = 2
ito = Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row ' find the row above the 1st blank cell in column E

name1 = "A"       
name2 = "B"    
audit = "C"      
currenc = "Dollars"       


For i = ifrom To ito

    text = Range("E" & i).Value
    score1 = Int(Range("B" & i).Value)
    score2 = Int(Range("C" & i).Value)
    score3 = Int(Abs(Range("D" & i).Value))


If score1 = 0 And score2 = 0 Then
    result = text + ......

ElseIf score1 = score2 Then
    result = text +........

ElseIf score1 > score2 And score2 <> 0 Then
    result = text + ............

ElseIf score1 < score2 And score1 <> 0 Then
    result = text +......

Else
    result = text + " 00000000"

End If

Range("H" & i).Value = result
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are these actual tables in Excel or simply look like tables? If actual tables then work with [list objects](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) and loop the list objects and the data body range rows of those list  objects.

Comment: "Code below works good, but it needs modernization." Best on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What is a difference between Stack and Code Review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also because your formulas are related just to same row you can try following which is more simple:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim score1 As Double, score2 As Double, score3 As Double, result As String, text As String

    Dim ifrom As Long, ito As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ifrom = 2
    ito = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'This row changed

    name1 = "A"
    name2 = "B"
    audit = "C"
    currenc = "Dollars"

    For i = ifrom To ito
        If Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then
            '.... Your code goes here
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Code works, but has mistake (debug) in part below:
    _score1 = Int(Range("B" & i).Value)
    score2 = Int(Range("C" & i).Value)
    score3 = Int(Abs(Range("D" & i).Value))_   
    First cell of next table is a **String**, and variables can't convert string to integer. Code gives Debug in this part. (As I understood reason of Debug). How to write condition "jump to next cell below when cell is a string?

Comment: In that case change If condition as bellow:    If Not IsNumeric(range("E" & i).value) Then

Comment: Changed but the same mistake. Maybe we have to write : not equal to string ?

Comment: Sorry for mistake:If should be :   IF IsNumeric(Range("E" & i).Value) Then

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

    '... Define your variables ....

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    name1 = "A"
    name2 = "B"
    audit = "C"
    currenc = "Dollars"

    ifrom = 2
    Do
        ito = Range("E" & ifrom).End(xlDown).Row ' find the row above the 1st blank cell in column E

        For i = ifrom To ito
            '... Your code comes here ...
        Next i
        ifrom = Range("E" & ifrom).End(xlDown).Row ' find top of next table, if no table return last row of worksheet
    Loop While ifrom < LastRow
End Sub
```